# Global Alert on any DAG Failure

Tags: airflow

I currently have over 100 DAGs running in production. I am aware of how to add alerting with `on_failure_callback` and with operators triggered by upstream failures, but is there a way to configure Airflow itself to always send an email when a DAG fails without having to go through and update every one of my DAGs to alert on failure individually?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not as far as I know, but I have this helper to handle my global/default dag/operator settings:

```
def on_failure_callback(context):
    ...

def on_success_callback(context):
    ...

def build_default_args(**kwargs):
    default_args = {
        'on_failure_callback': on_failure_callback,
        'on_success_callback': on_success_callback,
        'owner': 'me',
        'queue': 'default',
        'execution_timeout': timedelta(hours=1),
        'retries': 3,
        'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=10),
    }
    default_args.update(kwargs)
    return default_args
```

Then in each DAG:

```
dag = DAG(
    dag_id='my_dag',
    default_args=build_default_args(
        start_date=datetime(2017, 9, 20),
        execution_timeout=timedelta(hours=8),  # overrides default
    ),
    schedule_interval='@hourly',
)
```

Alternatively some custom base `DAG` class...but either way you would still have to go back and change your 100+ DAGs once.

Comment: Thanks for responding! Sorry for the extremely late acceptance.